# Building a Tree with Node Pairs

Tags: r, tree

I have a `data.table` of node pairs where Parent is higher up the tree than Child.

I need to extract all the individual chains from these rules e.g. if I have in format `parent>child`: (`a>b`, `b>c`, `b>e`, `c>d`), the chains are (`a>b>c>d`, `a>b>e`).

I've made an example with some dummy data showing what I want to do. Any suggestions on how to do this would be great? It feels like it should be straightforward but I'm struggling to think how to start. Thank you :)

```
library(data.table)
library(data.tree)
# example input and expected output
input <- data.table(Parent = c("a", "b", "c",
                               "e", "b"),
                    Child = c("b", "c", "d",
                              "b", "f"))
output <- data.table(Tree = c(rep(1,4), rep(2,3), rep(3,3), rep(4,4)),
                         List = c("a", "b", "c", "d",
                                  "e", "b", "f",
                                  "a", "b", "f",
                                  "e", "b", "c", "d"),
                         Hierarchy = c(1:4, 1:3, 1:3, 1:4))


# attempt with data.tree, only builds the node pairs.
# ignore world part, was following: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html#tree-creation
input[, pathString := paste("world", Parent, Child, sep = "/")]
data.tree::as.Node(input)

# attempt to re-structure
input[, Tree := .I]
dt1 <- input[, .(List = c(Parent, Child),
                 Hierarchy = 1:2), by=Tree]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another possible solution - a little messy as well though

**Output**

```
output(input)
#    tree_nums elems hierarchy
#  1:         1     a         1
#  2:         1     b         2
#  3:         1     c         3
#  4:         1     d         4
#  5:         2     e         1
#  6:         2     b         2
#  7:         2     c         3
#  8:         2     d         4
#  9:         3     a         1
# 10:         3     b         2
# 11:         3     f         3
# 12:         4     e         1
# 13:         4     b         2
# 14:         4     f         3   
#
```

**Function**

```
output <- function (input) {
  # init
  helper <- do.call(paste0, input)
  elements <- unique(unlist(input))
  res <- integer(length(elements))
  ind <- elements %in% input$Child
  # first generation
  parents <- elements[!ind]
  res[!ind] <- 1L
  # later generations
  val <- 1L
  parents <- parents
  trees <- setNames(as.list(seq_along(parents)), parents)
  while (any(res == 0L)) {
    val <- val + 1L
    children <- unique(input$Child[input$Parent %in% parents])
    res[elements %in% children] <- val

    # create the tree
    nextHelper <- expand.grid(parents, children)
    nextHelper$conc <- do.call(paste0, nextHelper)
    nextHelper <- nextHelper[nextHelper$conc %in% helper,]

    df_1 <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(names(trees),'')) 
    df_2 <- base::merge(df_1, nextHelper[,-3L], by.x = ncol(df_1), by.y = 'Var1', all.x = TRUE)
    n1 <- ncol(df_2)
    if (n1 > 2L) df_2 <- df_2[,c(2:(n1-1),1L,n1)]
    df_2$Var2 <- as.character(df_2$Var2)
    df_2$Var2[is.na(df_2$Var2)] <- ''


    treeNames <- do.call(paste0, df_2)
    trees <- setNames(as.list(seq_along(treeNames)), treeNames)
    parents <- children
  }

  elems <- strsplit(names(trees),'')
  tree_nums <- rep(as.integer(trees), lengths(elems))
  elems <- unlist(elems)
  output <- data.table::data.table(tree_nums,elems)
  out <- data.table::data.table(elements, res)
  output$hierarchy <- out$res[match(output$elems, out$elements)]
  output
}
```

Comment: Only thing I've found, which in hindsight I should have included in the e.g. is that the parent & children could have spaces e.g. "List A". This breaks yours (and my initial solution) as the helper needs to use a more distinct pattern when pasting together, one that's less likely to appear in the data :). I like the principle though, of finding the initial parents and building it that way, thank you

Comment: You mean something like `parent 1` or `child two`? If so, you could replace the white spaces by say `_`. I haven't tested but I'm thinking that might work.

Comment: yeah exactly, I agree it will be similar to the issue I had in mine, adding a variable for splitting/pasting together

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution after a bit of a slog, but would prefer something more efficient if it exists.

```
library(stringi)
# convert to string
setkey(input, Parent)
sep <- ">>"
split_regex <- "(?<=%1$s)[^(%1$s)]*$" 
trees <- sprintf("%s%s%s", input$Parent, sep, input$Child)
# get the base nodes, the children
children <- stri_extract_first_regex(trees, sprintf(split_regex, sep),
                                     simplify = TRUE)
# find that which are parents
grid <- input[J(unique(children)), ][!is.na(Child), ]
update <- unique(grid$Parent)
N <- nrow(grid)

while(N > 0){ 

  # add the children on for the ones at the base of the chains, might mean 
  # making more tree splits
  all_trees <- unique(unlist(lapply(update, function(x){
    pos <- children == x
    y <- grid[Parent %in% x, Child]
    trees <- c(trees[!pos], CJ(trees[pos], y)[, sprintf("%s%s%s", V1, sep, V2)])
    trees
  })))
  # I have some trees embedded now, so remove these ones
  trim <- sapply(seq_along(all_trees), function(i){
    any(stri_detect_fixed(all_trees[-i], all_trees[i]))
  })
  trees <- all_trees[!trim]

  # update operations on expanded trees until no children remain with a dependency
  children <- stri_extract_first_regex(trees, sprintf(split_regex, sep, sep),
                                      simplify = TRUE)
  grid <- input[J(unique(children)), ][!is.na(Child), ]
  update <- unique(grid$Parent)
  N <- nrow(grid)
}

# re-structure to appropriate format
output <- data.table(pattern = trees)
output[, Tree := 1:.N]
output[, split := stri_split_regex(pattern, sep)]
output <- output[, .(List = split[[1]],
                     Hierarchy = 1:length(split[[1]])), by=Tree]
output[]
```